# How to implement Dependent dropdown for postal code and city in drupal8?

Tags: drupal-8

We have a form in that we need two postcode and two city. I have created as entity reference field (Taxonomy). Created a taxonomy as with hierarchical order postcode as first level and cities mapped under postcode. I have totally 18k terms in single taxonomy. when i try to access the page i am getting Memory Limit error. In which i need to implement dependent dropdown. based on postcode selection cities need to be populated in city drop down field. Used Heirrchical select module. which is not suppported for large taxonomy. Any help.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by creating AJAX callback functions on form

Comment: This is not an answer. How about you give an example. Though the question is a little hard to answer given the seeming complexity of his set up.

Comment: Tried adding ajax callback, no luck. Because it is not event executing form alter function. Before itself i am getting memory limit error.